# How to compare a string with a string in pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I am implementing linked list in c++. In that am trying to compare a data stored in the node with a string. Here is my code:

```
String f; 
cin>>f; 
if(strcmp(temp->data,f)==0) 
    {  cout<<"same"; } 
else 
    { cout<<"not same"; }
```

Here is my error:

```
"assignment1.cc", line 160: Error: Cannot cast from std::string  to const char*.
"assignment1.cc", line 160: Error: Cannot cast from std::string  to const char*.
```

How to compare those two strings?

Comment: If temp is also `std::string` you could simply use `if (temp == f)`

Comment: And if `temp->data` is a `char*` you can use `f.c_str()`.

Comment: What is the declaration of `temp->data`?

Comment: @Barmar, since he's getting the cast error twice, I'm pretty sure it's a `string`, too.

Comment: @us2012 That's what I was suspecting. So it seems silly to use `c_str()` when you have two strings and can use string-specific functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to check for equality, you can simply use `operator==` to compare two `string`s. In your case, that seems to be:

```
if (data->temp == f)
```

---

However, if you want the functionality provided by `strcmp` (that is, if you need to know which string is larger lexicographically in case they are not equal), you can use `string::compare`:

```
if ( s1.compare(s2) < 0 )
```

Comment: I tried if(temp->data == f), it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the std::string::c_str method:

```
std::string f; 
cin>>f; 
if(strcmp(temp->data,f.c_str())==0) 
    cout<<"same";
else 
    cout<<"not same";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use f's "compare()" operator (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) or you can use operator ==

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string f("hello world");
    const char* p = "hello world";

    if (f == p)
        std::cout << "f == p" << std::endl;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/TTXRZv